# Necessary and suffcient condition for LR-decompositions

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, lu-decomposition

Let $ A=\left(a_{i j}\right)_{i, j=1, \ldots, n} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $ be an invertible matrix.

Show that an $ L R $-decomposition of $ A $ exists if and only if $ \operatorname{det}\left(A^{[k]}\right) \neq 0 $ for all $k=1, \ldots, n $, where $ A^{[k]} \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times k}, 1 \leq k \leq n $ is defined as
$
A^{[k]}:=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1 k} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{k 1} & \cdots & a_{k k}
\end{array}\right) \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times k}
$

Hint: You may use the following theorem without proof:

Let $ A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $ be given. Then for each lower triangular matrix $ L \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $ it holds
$
(L \cdot A)^{[k]}=L^{[k]} \cdot A^{[k]}, \quad k=1, \ldots, n
$.

Comment: Do you see how the hint theorem may be applied?

Comment: I think it has something to do with the determinant rules.